# Creating custom permalink tags for WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

You guys already know about the tags available for posts to be used in permalink structure like `%postname%, %post_id%, %author%` etc. Though it works for the post type, it doesn't work for products(WooCommerce) by default.

I am trying to include an author tag for `WooCommerce products` also. So that if I use this for products, the username of the product author will be visible in product permalinks.

I searched google for a good amount of time. Unfortunately, plugins are suggested for this. As I am trying this for learning purpose, I want to implement this using code instead of plugins. Any `insight/guide` on how I can implement this would be a great help.

Thanks.